# PHP SQL Get Date Time from Username and compare to todays date

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql

I want to get Date Time from specified Username and compare to todays date. I'm using a database.

```
  $con = mysqli_connect("server", "name", "pass", "db");
  if(!$con) {
    die("noconn");
  }
  
  $HWID = "";
  if(isset($_POST['HWID']) && !empty($_POST['HWID'])) {
    $HWID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['HWID']);
    $HWID = ($HWID);
  }
  elseif(isset($_GET['HWID']) && !empty($_GET['HWID'])) {
    $HWID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['HWID']);
    $HWID = ($HWID);
  } else {
    die("nodata");
  }

  $rows= "";
  if(isset($_GET['Expire_Date'])){
      $id=$_GET['Expire_Date'];
      $sql="SELECT HWID FROM users WHERE Expire_Date='$id'";
      $result=mysql_query($sql); 
      $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  }

  if (strtotime((new DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")) > strtotime($rows)) {
    die("valid");
  } else {
    die("invalid");
  }
```

The code works together with C#

```
    dataToSend["HWID"] = HWID();
    string GetData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.UploadValues(@"http://127.0.0.1/test.php", dataToSend));

    if (GetData == "valid")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("date is valid", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if (GetData == "invalid")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("date is not valid", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

Let's say HWID (Hardware ID) is an username 18585B53C213CA86DE91BE1E2772D66C6EC3F32F in a database and there's a date specified 2021-07-01. So when the date will run out, it will tell invalid, otherwise if it's not out, it'll tell valid. Every time I try this code it gives me valid. I'm not sure if I specified the username correctly or didn't compare correctly.

Comment: `strtotime($rows)` - you're attempting to create a timestamp from an array containing data of the whole row. You need to select just one column, the one containing the actual date.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You are mixing APIs in PHP. `mysql_query` doesn't exist

Comment: `strtotime((new DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")` looks way too overcomplicated. Why not just use `time()` instead?

Comment: `$HWID = ($HWID);` doesn't make much sense either.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be using prepared statements. If you want to use mysqli then I show you how to do it below, but I would strongly recommend learning PDO instead.

You can check `DateTime` objects against themselves. No need to use the old `strtotime()` function. You just need to select the single value from the database.

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect("server", "name", "pass", "db");

$HWID = "";
if (!empty($_POST['HWID'])) {
    $HWID = $_POST['HWID'];
} elseif (!empty($_GET['HWID'])) {
    $HWID = $_GET['HWID'];
} else {
    die("nodata");
}

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Expire_Date FROM users WHERE HWID=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $HWID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$Expire_Date = $row->Expire_Date;

if (new DateTime() > new DateTime($Expire_Date)) {
    die("valid");
} else {
    die("invalid");
}
```

Comment: I noticed that it gives a HWID to compare and not the database time from a specified HWID.

Comment: @MattThhh Yeah, I didn't really know where you were getting the date from

Comment: I want to get the database time from a specified HWID in database. [This is how the database are looking](https://prnt.sc/13o2t59)

Comment: I removed the GET input and swapped around the SELECT statement. Is this what you meant?

Comment: It says undefined variable Expire_Date on line 23

Comment: @MattThhh It's defined two lines above

Comment: I get blank as output so I did like that
[Link](https://hastebin.com/zinasoqoma.php)

Comment: If `$_GET['Expire_Date']` is not set then `$Expire_Date` won't be set either. I removed that line from my answer as I have no idea what you were trying to do there

Answer (score -1):

As El_Vanja say, your problem is the `strtotime($rows)`. When you fetch your rows with `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);` you get an array with all selected columns(see [doc here](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), you should take care it's depreciated since PHP 5.5 and remove from PHP 7.0 and above).
When you read the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime) of strtotime your first argument must be a string.

To fix your error you just have to replace `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);` by `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result[0]);` or `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result["HWID"]);`. Personnaly I prefer the second one is more readable.